# Calling BroadCast receiver from main activity android

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, boot

I want to start broadcast receiver class from my app's main activity. Main activity has all the GUI stuff, this activity starts a service which performs all the work. For making this service start after reboot, I have written a broadcast receiver class. Now I am confused where to call broadcast receiver class.

- How can I call it from my main activity (I don't want to make main activity a broadcast reciver)?
- If I call broadcast receiver from main activity, will it create a new instance of the broadcast class every time the activity starts. If so, will it cause memory leaks or the previous broadcast receiver instance will automatically be destroyed?

Regards

Comment: Should you also call it when user starts your application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a solution you may apply your own intent filter to `BroadcastReceiver` , register it and then call `sendBroadcast()` in your activity just after registering the receiver. This suppose that you compare intents which comes to your receiver inside of `onReceive()` method.

What about memory, it depends on how do you manage your activity's lifecycle, because in a case of remaining references to your activity it will not be removed from the memory and so will cause creation of multiple instances of your receiver.

And you also may add `android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED` intent filter to start your receiver after device's booting

Comment: What is the need of calling Receiver if receiver only starts the Service?

Comment: how to call in `onDestory()` of activity

Answer (score 0):

You can broadcast a message from any Activity (incl. your main activity) or Class. I am using a helper class to do this:

```
public class BroadcastHelper {

public static void sendBroadcast(Context context, String message, Serializable value) {

    Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();
    broadcastIntent.setAction(message);
    broadcastIntent.putExtra(Constants.BROADCAST_MESSAGE, value);
    context.sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);

}
```

}

Don't forget to register your receiver in manifest file.

Using this approach wan't create new instances of any class, except of the intent itself, which will be garbage collected.